# How to design my Django app database to accommodate multiple level information of an item?

Tags: django, database, database-schema

I am trying to create an app on Django. Struggling on how to proceed on Database schema.

There are the following tables:

1), table `customer`:

- cust_name
- cust_addr
- cust_phone
- created_date
- ...

2), table `customer_assets`

- customer                  (foreign key pointed to table `customer`)
- asset_type
- asset
- asset_update_time
- asset_creation_time
- ...

The major issue is on asset, asset_type, sample data like below:

```
asset_type      asset
------------------------------------------
domain          aaa.bb.example.com
domain          *.corp.example.com
ip          10.1.2.3
ip          10.8.0.0/16
url         http://aaaa
url         http://bbbbb
url         http://aaa.bb.example.com/app1/login
email           xxx@example.com
```

there are some assets like `*.corp.example.com`, `10.8.0.0/16`. The app is supposed to do a discovery and find more assets under them, for example:

- aaa.corp.example.com
- bbb.corp.example.com
- ccc.corp.example.com
- 10.8.2.2
- 10.8.2.3
- ...

The app is then going to scan the open ports on each of them, like:

- aaa.corp.example.com.    (22, 80, 1080)
- 10.8.2.2                 (21, 139, 3306)

the app may then scan every ports on the assets to find urls, like:

- aaa.corp.example.com        80           /home.html
- aaa.corp.example.com        80           /admin.html
- bbb.corp.example.com        443          /console

Note that:

- data in `customer_assets` is basically provided by customer
- data in `customer_assets` contains data of various types, for example,

1), wildcard sub domains (*.corp.example.com) and exact subdomains (aaa.bb.example.com).

2), exact subdomains in wildcard sub domains (*.corp.example.com) will later be discovered

what's the best way to organise the database schema?

1), is the current database schema for `customer_assets` ok?

2), where the discovered subdomains like `aaa.corp.example.com` be stored? should it be added to `customer_assets` as a new item,
or should I create a new table for it?

3), where to store the data of `ports`, and URLs for each `port`?

The customer might need to search there data by domain name, by port, by strings in URL, etc.

thanks

I have created table 1), table `customer` and table `customer_assets`, and it works fine.

but struggling how to proceed to store the data discovered for domain like `*.corp.example.com`, and how to store more detailed information discovered like ports for each subdomain (like ports 80, 22 for `aaa.corp.example.com`), and URLs discovered for each ports (like `/admin.html` for `aaa.corp.example.com` on port `80`)